# How to find integral solutions of a integral binary quadratic form?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

How to find all integral solutions of $f(x, y) = 2x^2-xy-3y^2=8$? I know that the solutions of this equation are in a bijection with $\alpha \in M_f$ where $N(\alpha) = 16$. But I don't know how to use this fact to solve the problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$        (x+y)(2x-3y)  = 8                          $$

................

Comment: How dumb I am. I was so biased by the methods I currently learned that I couldn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^2-xy-3y^2-8=0 \implies 3y^2+xy-2x^2+8=0 \implies y=\frac{-x\pm \sqrt{25x^2-96}}{6}$$
Let $$25x^2-96=m^2 \implies 25x^2-m^2=96 \implies (5x+m)(5x-m)=96$$
Factorise $$96=48\times 2 \implies 5x+m=48, 5x-m=2 \implies x=5, m=23 \implies y= 3$$
Simlarly,
$$96=12\times 8 \implies 5x+m=12, 5x-m=8\implies x=2, m=2 \implies y=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$ 2x^2-xy-3y^2=8$  -------$(1)$

Knowing a numerical solution (p,q) to equation (1)

another numerical solution can be arrived at by

using the formula below:

$x=(1/2)*(5p-7q)$

$y=(1/2)*(3p-5q)$

for known, $(p,q)=[(14/4),(11/6)]$ we get another

solution after substituting in the above:

$(x,y)=[(7/3),(4/3)]$